# Divide a Text Document into Sections using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm parsing a text file that has a semi-known repeating structure. There is a heading (1 line), a sub-heading(1 line or 2 lines), and a content area (arbitrary # of lines).
The format for each item in the document is shown below:

```
 
=========================
       Head Text 1
=========================
      SubHead Text1
      SubHead Text2
=========================
 Content Text Line 1
 Content Text Line 2
 ...
 Content Text Line 8

=========================
       Head Text 2
=========================
      SubHead Text1
      SubHead Text2
=========================
 Content Text Line 1
 Content Text Line 2
 ...
 Content Text Line 6
```

I would like each section to be inside a unique object, each with 3 sections... somethign like

```
section1.head
section1.subHead
section1.content

section2.head
section2.subHead
section2.content
```

The only way I can think of accomplishing this involves a lot of `if` and `while` statements. Is there an efficient way of accomplishing this?

I originally tried writing some code in JScipt, but I'm reading a RTF file and C# provides an easy way of converting RTF to plain text. It didn't work very well, I kept skipping some dividers and would get an error at the end of the file.

```
page = new Array();

fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.GetFile("test.rtf");

is = f.OpenAsTextStream( forReading, -2 );

var count = 0;
while( !is.AtEndOfStream ){
   page[count] = is.ReadLine();
   count++; ;
}

is.Close();

WScript.Echo( page[0].text);

var item = [];

var section = 0;

var i = 0, k = 0;
while (i < page.length) {
item[k] = {};

    if (!page[i].indexOf("=====")) { 
        i++;    
        item[k].head = page[i];
        i+=2;
        while(page[i].indexOf("=====")) {   // WScript.Echo( "index = " + i + " "+ page[i] +"\n" + "Next index = " + (i+1) + " "+ page[i+1] +"\n" );
            item[k].subHead += page[i];
            i++;
        }

        k++;

    } 
    i++;
}
```

Comment: So what did you try? It's a relatively simple line-based processing problem.

Comment: Can you please post some code of what you have already tried?

Comment: What I came up with just seemed so ugly and it didn't work very well either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut on the IFs, you could implement a state pattern submitting each line to the current state.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern